# C# - GDAL write raster for JPEG

Tags: c#, gdal

I have to write a JPEG image with GDAL in C#. The code I am using is given below

```
Driver drv = Gdal.GetDriverByName("JP2ECW");

int bXSize = width;
int bYSize = 1;

string[] options = new string[] { "BLOCKXSIZE=" + bXSize, "BLOCKYSIZE=" + bYSize };
Dataset dt = drv.Create(outImage, width, height, 3, DataType.GDT_Float32, options);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

What is the correct method to write raster bands in a JPEG file using GDAL?

Comment: What is the value in the variables `outImage`, `width`, `height`? I looked for similar problems on the forums - the variables must be pre-initialized